# Proof: For what positive integers k is it the case that the complement of a k-cycle is also a k-cycle?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am really confused and would really appreciate help regarding this question.

For what positive integers k is it the case that the complement of a k-cycle is also a k-cycle? Prove your answer.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. That said I'm voting to close this question  because I can't figure out what you are asking. Is this a $k$-cycle in a permutation group? If so, what is the complement of a cycle? If you edit the question to provide much more context, along with your attempt at a solution, perhaps we can help.

Comment: @EthanBolker If you write `[edit]`, then it creates a link to the edit box, like so: [edit].

Comment: @Shaun Testing [edit]  and it works. Thank you very much.

Comment: This was all the information that was provided to me, that is why I am so confused, and was hoping for someone to point me towards a direction to solving this problem.

Comment: Is a k-cycle in this sense a graph with all k nodes connected in a cycle and no other edges?

Comment: @EthanBolker.  The person needs some mathematical prompting such  as is this a permutation group?  He does not need this "shut up" rudeness of closing the question.  Asking for context is the polite response.

Comment: Hint. If this is a question about graph theory, and the complement of a set of edges is the set consisting of the other edges, think about two disjoint triangles.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

The degree of every node in a cycle is 2, since you are connected to the neighbor before and after you.

The degree of a node in a graph's complement is a simple function of its degree in the original graph and the order of the graph.

Writing these two equations starts your proof.